# Cache policy not updated according to PageSpeed

Tags: htaccess, cache

I am trying to update my cache policy by adding some directives in the .htaccess file in the root of my website. Although I updated the values for javascript files to be 1 month, when using Google PageSpeed, it still displayed the previous cache values (6 hours). Why is this?

```js
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 14 days"
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
> ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
> ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 14 days"
> ```

In order to determine the correct mime-type to use you need to look at the `Content-Type` HTTP response header from your server (using your browser). The default for JavaScript files is `application/javascript` - which you've not included here at all. You only need 1 directive that matches the response from your server, not 3 or 4. (You also stated `14 days` for the last directive above?)

For example:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
```

However, you also appear to be using an external host (CDN?) to serve some of your JS resources - these will obviously not be influenced by the directives on your application server. I also notice that the final response is coming from an Nginx server (possibly a proxy) - this might also be controlling the cache headers.

The `<IfModule mod_expires.c>` wrapper is not required unless you intend to port your code to multiple servers where mod_expires is not installed and it is OK for these directives to fail.

> when using Google PageSpeed, it still displayed the previous cache values (6 hours)

You should be manually checking the HTTP response headers `Cache-Control` (and `Expires`) in the browser to determine whether your directives are working or not.

Comment: Thank you! That was very enlightening :D